# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'Sequence' for data generator

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im trying to do a video frame generator using Keras but I am getting the above error.
For neural network training the method Keras.model.fit_generator is used.
This requires a generator that reads and yields training data to the Keras engine.

```
import glob
import os
import sys
#from gtts import utils
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import keras
from frame import files2frames, images_normalize, frames_show


class FramesGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    """Read and yields video frames/optical flow for Keras.model.fit_generator
    Generator can be used for multi-threading.
    Substantial initialization and checks upfront, including one-hot-encoding of labels.
    """

    def __init__(self, sPath: str, \
                 nBatchSize: int, nFrames: int, nHeight: int, nWidth: int, nChannels: int, \
                 liClassesFull: list = None, bShuffle: bool = True):
        """
        Assume directory structure:
        ... / sPath / class / videoname / frames.jpg
        """

        'Initialization'
        self.nBatchSize = nBatchSize
        self.nFrames = nFrames
        self.nHeight = nHeight
        self.nWidth = nWidth
        self.nChannels = nChannels
        self.tuXshape = (nFrames, nHeight, nWidth, nChannels)
        self.bShuffle = bShuffle
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue. Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!